# Strange issue with Dell PowerEdge R610 hard drive status lights

Tags: storage, led, sas, dell-poweredge, raid6

I setup a test FreeNAS server the other day on a spare Dell PowerEdge r610 and noticed that the hard drive activity LEDs are always both lit no matter what the server is doing.  I have 6 1TB 7.2k SAS drives installed and the raid controller is configured to use RAID 6 across all 6 drives.  FreeNAS is installed on an internal USB installed in the server.  Anyone have any idea why both of the HDD status LEDs would be on 100% of the time?  I noticed that when I reboot the server, right when the drives are being initialized, the LEDs look normal (top LED is lit, bottom status LED is not lit) but after the boot process gets half way through POST where it shows the dell logo, both top and bottom LEDs stay on at all times.

[image]

Comment: Check which process is doing I/O on the disk.

Comment: But it starts even before the OS loads, during the dell boot screen.

Comment: Perhaps the RAID controller is doing some maintenance work? Let it do its work for some hours or a day or two.